# "Untrusted TLS Certificate" on Azure Website

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, ssl-certificate, tls1.3

On my Azure Website, I am using "managed" certificates. I had a security scanner (intruder.io) scan the site and one result was "Untrusted TLS Certificate". The details point out that there is a "common name mismatch" and "ssl certificate with wrong hostname".

The actual hostname is "www.die.de", while the common name is " waws-prod-am2-007.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net".

I do not see any errors or warnings when visiting the site in any browser, however, the warning from intruder.io is making me nervous. Should i do something about this and if so, what should i do about this?

Comment: That server, like most today (especially cloud ones) requires SNI to select the correct cert; in addition both the with-SNI cert (for www.die.de) and the default one (for azurewebsites and azure-mobile) use SAN which means CommonName MUST be ignored. Both SNI and SAN have been nearly universal for a decade (including browsers) so 'intruder.io' (whatever that is) is obviously WAY out of date. PS: waws-prod-am2-007a.sip.azurewebsites.windows.net is one of your DNS CNAMEs, but it is not in the cert as either CN or SAN; both of those are wildcards. ...

Comment: ... For a more accurate analysis see https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.die.de -- note the summary item "works only ... with SNI support" and the second certificate block headed "No SNI", as well as the Alternative names items in _each_ of the two certificates. (And revel in your top-of-class A+ grade!)